# How to get rid of underline for Link component of React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following:

[image]

How do I get rid of the blue underline?
The code is below:

```
<Link to="first"><MenuItem style={{paddingLeft: 13, textDecoration: 'none'}}> Team 1 </MenuItem></Link>
```

The MenuItem component is from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu

Comment: put `textDecoration: 'none'` on the `<Link />` component not its children.

Answer (score 380):

I see you're using inline styles. `textDecoration: 'none'` is used in child, where in fact it should be used inside `<Link>` as such:

```
<Link to="first" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
  <MenuItem style={{ paddingLeft: 13 }}>Team 1</MenuItem>
</Link>
```

`<Link>` will essentially return a standard `<a>` tag, which is why we apply `textDecoration` rule there.

Comment: there a way to set global with textdecoration none ? in the app.css ?

Comment: It works :). Be aware that if you copy paste the style to your .css (because, of course, you don't like inline styles) then is `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: <Button variant="link" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
      Logout</Button>

Answer (score 181):

I think the best way to use react-router-dom Link in a MenuItem (and other MaterialUI component such as buttons) is to pass the Link in the "component" prop

```
<Menu>
   <MenuItem component={Link} to={'/first'}>Team 1</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem component={Link} to={'/second'}>Team 2</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

you need to pass the route path in the 'to' prop of the "MenuItem" (which will be passed down to the Link component). 
In this way you don't need to add any style as it will use the MenuItem style

Comment: Yours should definitely be the answer in 2019.

Comment: This is 100x better than the docs, they loooove lots of useless code

Comment: All other answers scare me

Comment: Although it's simplified, I think it may suffer from props collision. You may take this into your consideration.
https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-prop-forwarding

Comment: Or shouldn't be rather <MenuList> instead of <Menu> ...

Comment: @drazewski MenuList It's exposed to help customisation of the Menu component, so if you need to do that yes, you should use it, but in the case reported here it is about the MenuItem customisation so Menu should be enough.

Comment: @Mateen is right. this doesn't work for all cases, as opposed to the longer solutions

Answer (score 100):

If you are using `styled-components`, you could do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
    text-decoration: none;

    &:focus, &:hover, &:visited, &:link, &:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
`;

export default (props) => <StyledLink {...props} />;
```

Answer (score 91):

There's also another way to properly remove the styling of the link. You have to give it style of `textDecoration='inherit'` and `color='inherit'` you can either add those as styling to the link tag like:

```js
<Link style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}}>
```

or to make it more general just create a css class like:

```css
.text-link {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

And then just `<Link className='text-link'>`

Comment: have you tried my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55693040/3000540

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it also removes the change in color. Also, is there a way to translate that CSS class into JSS? I had the same issue using material-ui and using the style prop helped.

Comment: this rather worked for me 
a:hover{
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: This works for me. And this way is easier than others. Thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

You can add `style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}` in your `Link` component to remove the underline. You can also add more `css` in the `style` block e.g. `style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }}`.

```
<h1>
  <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }} to="/getting-started">
    Get Started
  </Link>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If someone is looking for `material-ui`'s Link component. Just add the property `underline` and set it to none

`<Link underline="none">...</Link>`

Answer (score 10):

There is the nuclear approach which is in your App.css (or counterpart)

```
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

which prevents underline for all `<a>` tags which is the root cause of this problem

Comment: Not a solution for react and styled-jsx…

Comment: actually its a solution it worked for me as im using sass beside my react and using all above solutions did not trigger <link> component style ..

Answer (score 10):

### Material UI v5+

You should be able to globally customize MUI component styles, such as:

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material'

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiLink: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textDecoration: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

const App = ({ currentAccount, neighborhoodsWithPropertyCount }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </ThemeProvider>
)

export default App
```

However, more often than not, you should actually be using the Link component from `react-router-dom`, in which case links would have no text decoration by default.

Answer (score 7):

//CSS

```
.navigation_bar > ul > li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline;
      margin: 2%;
    }

    .link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

//JSX

```
 <div className="navigation_bar">
            <ul key="nav">
              <li>
                <Link className="link" to="/">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Its pretty simple. Just add this `style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}` inside of your `<Link>` tag

```
<Link to="first" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
   <MenuItem style={{ paddingLeft: 13 }}>
         Team 1
   </MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 4):

The underline comes by default from the `react-router-dom` package. You can do the following to fix the issue.

```
<Link to="/route-path" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}> 
    // Rest of the code
</Link>
```

Comment: This will work, and to make life easier you can also make a re-useable component like <BaseStyleLink/> and use that so you don't have to repeatedly apply this styling across your whole app.

Answer (score 3):

Working for me, just add `className="nav-link"` and `activeStyle{{textDecoration:'underline'}}`

```
<NavLink className="nav-link" to="/" exact activeStyle= 
  {{textDecoration:'underline'}}>My Record</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look here -> https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#button.

This is the official material-ui guide. Maybe it'll be useful to you as it was for me.

However, in some cases, underline persists and you may want to use text-decoration: "none" for that. For a more cleaner approach, you can import and use makeStyles from material-ui/core.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    menu-btn: {
        textDecoration: 'none',
    },
}));

const classes = useStyles();
```

And then set className attribute to {classes.menu-btn} in your JSX code.

Answer (score 3):

**CSS Solution also for React**

1. *Add className/class in the Link(React Router) tag only.***(Most Important Part!! Add ClassName in Link tag not any other.)**
2. *Add text-decoration: none in the css file.*

Nav.js

```
  <Link to="/" className="link" >
    Get Started
  </Link>
```

Nav.css

```
.link{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Remove the blue color.
.link{
text-decoration: none;
color          : unset;
}

Answer (score 2):

jsx:

```
<Link className="link">
  test
</Link>
```

css:

```
.link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look all that different from this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54089880/4294399

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [@Grgur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37670759/1923016), if you look in your inspector, you'll find that using `Link` components gives them the preset color value `color: -webkit-link`. You'll need to override this along with the `textDecoration` if you don't want it to look like a default hyperlink.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
style={{ backgroundImage: "none" }}
```

Only this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve a problem maybe like your. I tried to inspect element in firefox.
I will show you some results:

1. It is only the element I have inspect. The "Link" component will be convert to "a" tag, and "to" props will be convert to the "href" property:

[image]

2. And when I tick in :hov and option :hover and here is result:

[image]

As you see a:hover have text-decoration: underline. I only add to my css file:

```
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

and problem is resolved. But I also set text-decoration: none in some another classes (like you :D), that may be make some effects (I guess).

Answer (score 1):

```
<Link
   to='/maxpain'
   replace
   style={{
           textDecoration: 'none'
          }}
   >
     <LinkText>Click here!</LinkText>
</Link>
```

Simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

the `<Link />` tag basically is `<a>` tag on render time, so you can just write

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

and it worked for me :)
Good luck

Comment: This has been stated several times by others. You could improve your answer by citing documentation and providing formatted code samples.

Answer (score 1):

I found two main ways:

**with [MUI Link API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/link/)**

```
 import { Link } from '@mui/material';

 <Link
    href={`https://www.example.com/?symbol=${myValue}`}
    underline="none"
    color="inherit"
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
         >
    {myValue}
  </Link>
```

**or with [MUI sx props](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)**

```
  <Link
    href={`https://www.example.com/?symbol=${myValue}`}
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
    sx={{
      color: '#42a5f5'
      textDecoration: 'none',
      display: 'inline',
      fontWeight: 'light'
      mx: 0.5,
      fontSize: '0.80rem',
    }}
  >
    {value.toUpperCase()}
  </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to="/page">
    <Box sx={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
        <PLink variant="primary">Page</PLink>
    </Box>
</Link>
```

In some cases when using another component inside the Gatsby `<Link>` component, adding a `div` with `display: 'inline-block'` around the inner component, prevents underlining (of 'Page' in the example).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply use this piece of code in your scss file;
This will remove that unwanted color change,

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
  &:hover {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the Link element was changing my h4 to 'underline', setting text-decoration: 'none' did not work, my only solution was to use a button instead.

```
<Link to="/settings">
    <button>Settings</button>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

standard a-link  and  react-link are the same.

so if you are styling a-link, it will automatically style react-link.

a{
what ever styling you want
}

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
<Link
   to={`$path`}
   style={{ borderBottom: "none" }}> 
    .... 
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this question and no one of the answers really resolve the problem at all in a general case (e.g. if the elements isn't a MenuItem). I suggest:

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
const MyComp = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return <div>
    <AnyComponent onclick={()=>history.push('/path/u/want')}
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added two lines and worked for me :)

```
{
 text-decoration: none; 
 color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: black !important; 
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

used !important in App.css

Answer (score 0):

Add css style in

```
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cc850a;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cc850a;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #47a1ad;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 and `has` pseudo-class [is widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has). Since MenuItems are rendered as `<li>` we can define a css rule like this:

```
a:has(> li) {
  text-decoration: unset;
  color: unset;
}
```

This only modifies `<a>` elements that have a `<li>` child element.

Answer (score 0):

One more for the pile:

`style={{textDecorationColor: "transparent"}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Polaris link, none of these answers will work and you'll go a little nuts looking at answers for React Link. For a Polaris Link, use removeUnderline={true}

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me is this:

```
<Link to="/" style={{boxShadow: "none"}}>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add this to your css file or styles to remove any link causing underline!

`a:-webkit-any-link{text-decoration: none;}`

Comment: Please note that this rule is only intended for WebKit browsers. Here's the rule's [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any-link).

Answer (score -2):

```html
<Link 
   _hover={{
      textDecoration: "none"
   }}
   >
   Logo
</Link>
```