# React-Router NavLink changes ripple colors on Material-UI ListItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm trying to wrap a Material-UI `<ListItem button>` into a react-router `<NavLink>`. Basically it's working fine, but I noticed that the `<NavLink>` Component changes the ripple colors on the `<ListItem button>`. If I wrap It the other way round (NavLink in ListItem) I won't be able to style the `<ListItem>` with `classes.linkActive` so that's not an option.

here is a minimal code-sample showing the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/xrxl90jv04

I've been looking through the components a bit but I'm kinda new to react, so any Ideas on how to prevent NavLink to change the colors or any way to tell the ListItem to use the default/theme palette again?

Comment: Do you think you could put your code in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/recent) or something similar? I'm not quite sure I understand your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't because it's for my employer...

Comment: Sure, not all of it, but a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's just like: normal ListItem component has grey ripple. If I wrap it into a NavLink component the ripple becomes red (and additionally there it gets a blue background on mouseUp)

Comment: Alright. I'm not sure how you are writing your CSS, but your could add [this CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669391/how-to-get-rid-of-underline-for-link-component-of-react-router#answer-48874424) to them.

Comment: i'm using Material-UI default JSS `withStyles()`

Comment: ok here is the code-sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/xrxl90jv04

Comment: Thanks, interesting. It seems to get a purple ripple as soon as it's inside an anchor tag. Doesn't matter if you use `Link`, or even `a`.

Comment: just found a good solution, check my answer haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wow, as most of the time, I answer my questions myself. Thanks to Tholle who told me to create a minimal working example, I noticed that the ripple color inside of `<NavLink>` depends on the text color (well basically it was only the color of the text-decoraion underline). so I simply added a style `color: 'inherit'` to the `<NavLink>` which is working like a charm :)

updated code is in the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xrxl90jv04

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a bunch of time!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer above I can do it, so, for posterior versions we have:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { NavLink as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ListItem, ListItemButton, ListItemText } from '@mui/material';
const LinkRouted = styled(ListItem)({
    color: "inherit"
})
export const ItemNavbar = (props) => {
  const {label:primary, route:to} = props.opt
  return (
    <LinkRouted component={RouterLink} to={to} disablePadding>
        <ListItemButton>
            <ListItemText primary={primary} />
        </ListItemButton>
    </LinkRouted>
  )
}
ItemNavbar.propTypes = {
    opt: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```