# Styling links in react

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to figure out how to style links in react.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669391/how-to-get-rid-of-underline-for-link-component-of-react-router) and tried most of it's suggestions.

I have defined a footer styling class as:

```
.footerlinks {
    a:link {color: $Hand3};
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: $secondary-font;
    a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color: #FAF5F2;};
    a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#FAF5F2;};
    a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#FAF5F2;};
    a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#FAF5F2;};
    color: $Hand3;
}
```

Then, I have a footer link as:

```
<Link to={'/about'} className="footerlinks">About</Link>
```

The 'color' css field applies, but none of the a tag links work. When you hover on a link it turns blue underline. The css inspector shows the webkit a styling has been misapplied, except for the pointer.

What's the trick to styling a tags in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work the same as with regular HTML and CSS. Assuming you are using react-router or similar, `Link` should generate an `a` tag.

I think the problem is where you have put the class. The CSS is expecting a component with the class `footerlinks` followed by an `a` element inside.

Try changing your code to:

```
<div className="footerlinks">
  <Link to={'/about'}>About</Link>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried a million versions of this, but not that one

Answer (score 0):

If you directly want to apply css on react links, you have another option that is

**You can use `<NavLink>` instead of `<Link>`**

```
<NavLink 
   className="CssClassForNormalLinks" 
   activeClassName={location.pathname !== "your pathname"? null : "CssClassForActiveLinks"}
   to="/home"
   >
   HOME
</NavLink>
```