# text decoration not working for mui lit items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using mui lists to create a sidebar.

```
 <List>
          <StyledLink to="/">
            <ListItem disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <GridView />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          </StyledLink>
 </List>
```

I tried creating a custom `Link` like below,

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const StyledLink = ({ to, style = {}, children }) => (
  <Link to={to} style={{ ...style, textDecoration: "none" }}>
    {children}
  </Link>
);

export default StyledLink;
```

I also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48874424/14912334).

But still the blue color doesn't go away and it doesn't inherit mui list item text formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`text-decoration: "none"` is only removing the underline style. You can get rid of the blue color by setting `color` attribute.

```js
style={{ ...style, textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}
```